# Nested data structure problem with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, react-hooks, structure

I have a project where I have to be able to create and edit a new document.
The Document has Categories, Categories have Parameters and Parameters have input boxes.. for input values.

The structure is the following:

```js
{
  documentName: "Example",
  category_1: {
    categoryName: "example category",
    parameter_1: {
      parameterName: "example parameter",
      value: 1234
      unit: "cm"
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I store names inside because those are not unique so one can appear multiple times.

Document, Category and Parameter are pretty big components because of the features they need to have.

They are nested:

```js
<Document>
  <Category setter={setValue} id=key={customGenerated}>
    <Parameter setter={setValue} id=key={customGenerated}>
      <CustomInputBox1 id=key={customGenerated}/>
      ...
      <CustomInputBox6/>
    </Parameter>
  </Category>
</Document>
```

At every level I do the same.

I have a dataObject which stores the data below it. I have separate setValue functions at every "level" that adds the new value to the dataObject and is passed down from its own level to the one below it.

DATAOBJECT:

```js
const [dataObject, setDataObject] = useState({});
```

SETTER OPTION A:

```js
const setValue = function (id, val) {             
    setDataObject({...dataObject, [id]: val});
}
useEffect( () => {
    if (setter) {
        setter(___id, dataObject);
    }
}, [dataObject]);
```

This one sends the data up when the component is re-rendered and the dataObject is changed.

---

SETTER OPTION B:

```js
const setValue = function (id, val) {     
    const newDo = {...dataObject, [id]: val};
    if (setter) {
        setter(catid, newDo);
    }
    setDataObject(newDo);
}
```

and this one sends the dataobject immediately up

---

### My problem

**It comes up when I load a document and I create multiple categories and they try to access the Documents dataObject at the same time.**
The problem is that (especially with option B) the renders mix up and sometimes the Documents dataObject is missing like a Category that is clearly visible just somehow deleted from the object and I don't even know why. I was thinking the reason is more Categories updating the Documents dataObject at the same time but Im not sure that would lead to complete Categories disappearing from the dataObject. I'm writing because I had no better idea, I wasted hours and hours trying to figure out what to do and I just got tired and hopeless.

**I read about Redux and the Flux datastructure**
and I'm either dumb or just too tired but I think that my problem would remain the same because I would try to access and modify the same source with multiple Categories at the same time.

---

my brains ded snd help ples

Comment: You don't need `redux`, `flux` or anything like those. What you need is a few functions that does `create`, `update` and `delete` a `document`, a `category` given a document and a `parameter` given a document and category.

Comment: @SamR. You are so right. Thank you for your time! Going to try it as soon as possible!